# How to add a header to a separator in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, header, separator

I would like to add a header to a WPF Separator (so that it looks like the top line of a GroupBox). The purpose of this is to separate the view into different sections, and I can't use a GroupBox because the guidelines in our business say that we must use separators for that... Does someone know how to do that?

EDIT:

I know it is possible to achieve this solution by using other controls (i.e. borders and textbox), but I want to know is if an Header property can be added to the Separator object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write you own custom control

```
public class HeaderedSeparator : Control
{
    public static DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Header",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(HeaderedSeparator));

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderedSeparator}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderedSeparator}">
                <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Separator Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
                    <Separator Grid.Column="2" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then use it:

```
<local:HeaderedSeparator Header="Header1"/>
<local:HeaderedSeparator Header="Header2"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
  <Grid Height="20">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Separator
        Width="20"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     <TextBlock
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="4, 0"
        Text="My Header"/>
     <Separator
        Grid.Column="2"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: That works but I'd like if something really uses the Separator object, so it would have the same look as other separators in other applications without having to map the exact same colors and widths and everything.

Comment: @Carl: you could use this as a control template for a `HeaderedContentControl` that you use in place of a `Separator` object.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Yeah I know I could do that, but if possible I would like to add a header to a real Separator so that I don't have to change all the style of the border to look exactly like a Separator. Maybe it's impossible, in which case I'll just use this solution, but if it is possible I would prefer that.

Comment: @Carl - they're separators now ;)

Comment: Haha I can't believe I didn't think about this (I'm feeling kind of stupid right now :P). Anyway thanks that works well!

Comment: Sorry I un-accepted your answer, but Navid's one is more like what I wanted.